# PHP regular expression not being matched - what is wrong?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
"^[x]{1}[a-z]{3,4}:[a-z0-9]{1,6}"
```

I want to use it to be able to match strings like:

**xabc:z123**

However, when I try it with [this regex tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm), it does not match the pattern. Is it my pattern that is wrong, or is the online tester unreliable?.

If my pattern is wrong, could someone point out why it is wrong.

Also, I want to make the pattern matching case insensitive - but I'm not too sure the best way to do that (thought better to ask rather than trial and error). How do I change the pattern so it matches irrespective of case?

Comment: Works fine for me on that test of yours with `^[x]{1}[a-z]{3,4}:[a-z0-9]{1,6}` as regexp (without the quotes). Case insensitive version [`/^[x]{1}[a-z]{3,4}:[a-z0-9]{1,6}/i`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#example-4213).

Comment: @rebus Yeah, I guess the OP wants to match groups (see my updated answer).

Comment: Don't know, doesn't say anything about the grups in question.

Comment: Make sure you don’t include the quotes in that regex tester as it already adds delimiters (I’m just assuming that you wanted to use the quotes as the delimiters now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `i` for case insensitive matching:

```
 /^[x]{1}[a-z]{3,4}:[a-z0-9]{1,6}/i
```

By the way, your regular expression works!?

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => xabc:z123
)
```

If you want to have something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'xabc:z123',
    [1] => 'x',
    [2] => 'abc'
    ...
)
```

You need to add groups using `()`, e.g.:

```
 /^([x]{1})([a-z]{3,4}):([a-z0-9]{1,6})/i
```

Comment: I actually, did not want groups. Could you please tell me the settings you used for the regex tester?. Specifically, which values did you use for 'Select Preg Type:' and 'Select Function:' ?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment now. As you accepted the answer, I guess it worked for you ;). Anyway: I just kept the defaults :).

Answer (score 2):

In the tester, you have to enter the regex without the surrounding quotes.  In PHP source code, you have to use quotes *and* a regex delimiter; the tester shows that in the code it generates:

```
$ptn = "/^[x]{1}[a-z]{3,4}:[a-z0-9]{1,6}/";
```

To make it case insensitive, you have two options.  One is to add an `i` after the closing delimiter, as @middus's answer demonstrates.  The other is to add `(?i)` to the the regex itself:

```
(?i)^[x]{1}[a-z]{3,4}:[a-z0-9]{1,6}
```

The tester will accept it either way; if you don't add the delimiters yourself it adds `/` to either end, which means any slashes in your regex need to be escaped (i.e., it doesn't escape them for you).  Be aware that PHP allows you to use other characters as the delimiters, but that tester only recognizes `/`.

Some further notes:

- To match a single `x`, all you need is `x`. The square brackets are unnecessary when there's only one letter inside them, and the `{1}` quantifier never has any effect--it's pure clutter.
- If you're using the regex to validate the string, you may want to add a `$` anchor to the end.

End result:

```
/^x[a-z]{3,4}:[a-z0-9]{1,6}$/i
```

**[Here](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/)** is another tester that lets you choose your own delimiters, among other things.